# My master told us to do the html and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I made some but I really can't find out how to display the "hidden" images of each box...
filter the friends list showing the names which match the name being entered by the textbox.
This is the html part of my code.

```
<html>
<head>  
    <title>My Memory Game</title>
    Enter Your Name: <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="ShowWelcomeMessage();">

    <h1 id="title"class="h1">My Memory Game</h1>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>   
</head>

<body>

    <ul style="float:left"><span style="cursor:pointer" class="game" onclick="Ngame();">New Game</span></ul>
    <ul style="float:left"><span style="cursor:pointer" class="about" onclick="about();">About</span></ul>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="a" class="box"></div>
        <div id="b" class="box"></div>
        <div id="c" class="box"></div>
        <div id="d" class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="e" class="box"></div>
        <div id="f" class="box"></div>
        <div id="g" class="box"></div>
        <div id="h" class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $("#box_button").click(function(){
        if(!$("#hiddenBox").show()) {
            $("#hiddenBox").show()
        } else {
            $("#hiddenBox").hide();
        }
    });
    </script>


    <div class="chatscrollable" style="position:fixed; bottom:80px; right:0px"> 

    <!---<div class="chatscrollable" style="right:-1000px; bottom:-150px; position:relative;"> -->

    <img src="marianne.jpg"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/marianne.pua">Marianne</a>
    <div align="right"><font color="green">Web</font> <div class= "online"> </div></div>

    <img src="warren.jpg"> <a href="http:www.facebook.com/wandoc">Warren</a>
    <div align="right"><font color="green">Mobile</font> <div class= "online"> </div></div>

    <img src="perry.jpg"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/perry.cabugao1">Perry</a>
    <div align="right"><font color="green">Web</font> <div class= "online"> </div></div>

    <img src="claire.jpg"> <a href="http:www.facebook.com/claire.austria">Claire</a>
    <div align="right"><div class= "mobile"> </div></div>

    <img src="aj.jpg"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/aj.garcia.58">Aj</a>
    <div align="right"><font color="green">Mobile</font> <div class= "online"> </div></div>

    <img src="rj.jpg"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/rowlandjasper">Rj</a>
    <div align="right"><font color="green">Mobile</font> <div class= "online"> </div></div>

    <img src="nona.jpg"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/nonagabrielle">Nona</a>
    <div align="right"><font color="green">Mobile</font> <div class= "online"> </div></div>

    <input type="text" id="name" />
```

And this is the functions in the JS:

```
function ShowWelcomeMessage() 
{
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = name+ "'s Memory Game";
}

function about() 
{
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    alert("This game is made by " + name + ". Copyright 2014")
}

function Ngame()
{
document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundImage = "url('frozen.jpg')";
document.getElementById("b").style.backgroundImage = "url('frozen.jpg')";
document.getElementById("c").style.backgroundImage = "url('frozen.jpg')";
document.getElementById("d").style.backgroundImage = "url('frozen.jpg')";
document.getElementById("e").style.backgroundImage = "url('frozen.jpg')";
document.getElementById("f").style.backgroundImage = "url('frozen.jpg')";
document.getElementById("g").style.backgroundImage = "url('frozen.jpg')";
document.getElementById("h").style.backgroundImage = "url('frozen.jpg')";
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is asking. Can you clarify

Comment: Please do not post code in the comment section. This should go in your question.

Comment: Sorry, my question here is how to display the "hidden" images of each boxes... and how filter the friends list showing the names which match the name being entered by the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
$("#box_button").click(function(){
    if(!$("#hiddenBox").is(":visible")) {
        $("#hiddenBox").show()
    } else {
        $("#hiddenBox").hide();
    }
});
```

because `.show()` returns the selected element and is therefore always evaluated as true. So this part of your code:

```
$("#box_button").click(function(){
    if(!$("#hiddenBox").show()) { // <--- will never be true thus
        $("#hiddenBox").show()    // <--- this line will never be executed
    } else {
        $("#hiddenBox").hide();   // <--- but always this one.
    }
});
```

will always call `$("#hiddenBox").hide();` and you don't want that.

---

Note that you can also use the native jQuery's [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method for that exact functionality.

Comment: @naveen I know, right! :) Have you seen this framework for jQuery: http://vanilla-js.com/ ;)

Comment: [But jQuery is amazing and does all wonderful things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/143130)

Comment: @naveen Haha, this is pure gold!

Comment: its hard not to love bobince ;) i loved the vanilla-js link. super cool

Comment: I have one more question, how to filter the friends list showing the names which match the name being entered by the textbox.

Comment: You're welcome. What list are you referring to? What should happen?

Comment: Sorry late.on the HTML I have there a friend list, it looks like a chat box. I want to make it like a search that when you type a name it will show what the name that match on what you type.

Comment: It might be the best idea to ask another question, just about that - we don't want to turn SO into a forum. Also, make sure you have some relevant code ready because there are so many ways to do that. For example, you can set the onchange listener to the input box, and upon every change redraw the friends list based on the value from that input. Hopefully this doesn't sound too confusing. I can show you a simple example a bit later if you don't do it till then.